# Format UTC from locale date in moment.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, momentjs, utc

I got such an object:

```
data: {
    date: "2019-08-26"
    time: "05:00"
}
```

I have also my timezone: `"Europe/Copenhagen"`

I want to create a UTC date with `moment.js` taking into account that my date data comes from the timezone. How can I do it?

I tried to do it with utc function, connecting strings manually, but it didn't work well.

EDIT: I use moment-timezone, so the `tz()` function is available. I don't want to use the browser timezone but the one defined as `"Europe/Copenhagen"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this function:

```
returnIsoUtcString(data: {date: string, time: string}, timezone: string) {
    const time = data.time + ':00';
    const fullDateInIso = moment(data.date + 'T' + time, moment.ISO_8601);
    const utcString = fullDateInIso.tz(timezone).utc().format();
    return utcString;
  }
```